# Hide subway stations from GMSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I have integrated the Google Maps api for iOS. I want to hide the subway stations from the map in New York City. Is there a way to do this with the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can call Javascript using UIWebViewtry to execute the JS function from Objective-C

Implement the UIWebView's delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad: in your UIViewController and in there you call [graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"methodName()"];

Then add

```
var styleArray = [

    featureType: "poi.transit.station",
    elementType: "labels",
    stylers: [
      { visibility: "off" }
    ]
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using the Google Maps SDK for iOS. There is no web view. I have a Mapview control